# Use tidyr::fill to fill missing values evenly above and below non-missing data

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataset covering 1945-2021 and census values for every tenth year (simplified below) and I am currently trying to use tidyr::fill to fill each census value for the five years before and after the census was taken (e.g. the 1991 census should apply to 1986 - 1995). However, my code takes the first census values and fills up and down to the next census value, which only fills down and so on.

```
dat_filled <- dat %>%
  fill(value, .direction = "downup")
```

Original data

```
#>  year    value
#>  1945    <NA>
#>  1946    A
#>  1947    <NA>
#>  1948    <NA>
#>  1949    <NA>
#>  1950    <NA>
#>  1951    <NA>
#>  1952    <NA>
#>  1953    <NA>
#>  1954    <NA>
#>  1955    <NA>
#>  1956    B
#>  1957    <NA>
#>  1958    <NA>
#>  1959    <NA>
#>  1960    <NA>
#>  1961    <NA>
#>  1962    C
#>  1963    <NA>
#>  1964    <NA>
```

What I currently get (first value, A, goes all the way down to the first occurrence of B, and then same for C)

```
#>  year    value
#>  1945    A
#>  1946    A
#>  1947    A
#>  1948    A
#>  1949    A
#>  1950    A
#>  1951    A
#>  1952    A
#>  1953    A
#>  1954    A
#>  1955    A
#>  1956    B
#>  1957    B
#>  1958    B
#>  1959    B
#>  1960    B
#>  1961    B
#>  1962    C
#>  1963    C
#>  1964    C
```

What I want (A does one 'updown', then B, then C, and then repeat until all NAs are filled)

```
#>  year    value
#>  1945    A
#>  1946    A
#>  1947    A
#>  1948    A
#>  1949    A
#>  1950    A
#>  1951    A
#>  1952    B
#>  1953    B
#>  1954    B
#>  1955    B
#>  1956    B
#>  1957    B
#>  1958    B
#>  1959    B
#>  1960    C
#>  1961    C
#>  1962    C
#>  1963    C
#>  1964    C
```

My actual data is slightly more complicated than this, but only due to one group_by function.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is using `join`:

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  mutate(year = map(year, ~seq(.x-5, .x+4)))%>%
  unnest(year) %>%
  right_join(df[1])
   year value
1  1945     A
2  1946     A
3  1947     A
4  1948     A
5  1949     A
6  1950     A
7  1951     B
8  1952     B
9  1953     B
10 1954     B
11 1955     B
12 1956     B
13 1957     B
14 1958     B
15 1959     B
16 1960     B
17 1957     C
18 1958     C
19 1959     C
20 1960     C
21 1961     C
22 1962     C
23 1963     C
24 1964     C
```

Comment: Very intuitive Mr. Onyambu! I really admire the way you approached this.